# gSoap: How to set or change cookies on client in Qt?

Tags: c++, qt, gsoap

I'am use next code for authorization on server by service, and get other service'methods using cookie identifer for authorizathion.

```
TerminalControllerBinding soapObj;
soap_init1(soapObj.soap, SOAP_C_UTFSTRING);
soapObj.endpoint = "http://192.168.*.*/path/to/service";

ns1__getTemplatesResponse *response = new ns1__getTemplatesResponse;

std::string auth_res = "";
soapObj.ns1__auth("user", "password", auth_res);

QString sessid = QString::fromStdString(auth_res);

qDebug() << sessid;

soapObj.soap->cookies = soap_cookie(soapObj.soap, "sessid", sessid.toAscii().data(), ".");
```

Server not getting cookie "sessid"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am kind of confused by the code you posted: You allocate memory for `ns1__getTemplatesResponse`, then do some apparently unrelated stuff; in fact you do not reference it again at all. Furthermore `soap_cookie` is a struct and `soap->cookies` is basically a list. So there is no magic that transfers the cookies to the server here.

I think what you want is `soap_set_cookie`. You can find a little more information on client side cookies [here](http://www.cs.fsu.edu/~engelen/soapdoc2.html#tth_sEc19.28), but there isn't any example code. Much more helpful however is actually the [server side](http://www.cs.fsu.edu/~engelen/soapdoc2.html#tth_sEc19.29) documentation (the handling of cookies doesn't differ much).

Also notice that you either need to compile with `-DWITH_COOKIES` or define the macro yourself in `stdsoap.h` if you haven't done so already.

Comment: Yes, indeed, with soap_set_cookie it worked. Thank you very much for your response.